# Chewing and weight loss/gain

Tags: food, digestion

I have a burning question. I have read many articles which say that chewing food properly, therefore longer, till you have a liquid-like texture, is causing you to eat less calories. However, it causes you to absorb more nutrients. If you would eat the same amount of food. Would chewing make a difference in your weight gain/loss?

Comment: I'm assuming that what they are referring to is really not about chewing more, but rather eating more slowly. There is a lot of research that shows that satiety (not necessarily feeling 'full', but feeling satisfied/no longer hungry) is delayed relative to actual eating, so that if you eat more slowly you tend to feel just as satisfied despite eating less. Therefore, that claim is completely predicated on the assumption that you will *not* eat the same amount of food by chewing more. They should really be more precise, but vague diet advice seems to sell books/get views.